# Get separate the integer and decimal part

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem regarding the integer part and decimal part of a number. Actually what I need is say I have a number '101'. this is actually came after some calculations and its time. I need to find the hrs and min. So what I did is

```
              overtime = 101
                    Dim fraction As Decimal = 0
                    If overtime > 59 Then
                        fraction = overtime / 60
                        'overtime = overtime / 60
                        fraction = fraction - CInt(fraction)
                        fraction = fraction * 60
                        Dim str() As String = Split(fraction.ToString, ".")
                        Try
                            If str(2).Length > 2 Then

                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try

                    End If
```

but the integer is getting rounded so that I get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `\` operator (opposite direction slash from the normal division operator), which automatically truncates off the decimal portion leaving only an integer, and the `Mod` operator, which returns only the remainder of a division operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `TimeSpan` to do the conversion for you:

```
 Dim overtime As Integer = 101
 Dim ov As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(overtime)

 ' outputs "Hours: 1 Minutes: 41"
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hours: {0} Minutes: {1}", ov.Days * 24 + ov.Hours, ov.Minutes))
```

`overtime` could also be of any other type which can be converted to a `Double`.